# PonyDebugger not showing any network requests

Tags: ios, ponydebugger

I am trying out PonyDebugger with a simple iOS application and I'm not seeing any network requests in the inspector view.

I tried loading a single http request with NSURLConnection and opening a web page in UIWebView.

In the inspector I *can* see the client, I can open it, I *can* see the view hierarchy and I can also get PDLog output in the console. It's just the network traffic that isn't showing.

I'm initializing PD like this:

```
PDDebugger *debugger = [PDDebugger defaultInstance];
//[debugger autoConnect];
[debugger enableNetworkTrafficDebugging];
[debugger forwardAllNetworkTraffic];
[debugger enableViewHierarchyDebugging];
[debugger enableRemoteLogging];
[debugger connectToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://192.168.5.127:9000/device"]];
```

What's the correct way to setup network debugging for PonyDebugger?

Comment: not sure if it makes any difference - but in my code i first do connectToURL and then i enableNetworkTrafficDebugging and forwardAllNetworkTraffic. And it works fine.

Comment: @SimonMeyer tried that as well, no luck.

Comment: The caching can be pretty extreme in iOS.  Requests will not appear if they've been cached by NSURLCache.  Have you tried resetting your simulator?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that for my test, made purely to try out PonyDebugger, I implemented only

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    PDLog( @"Received data" );
}
```

because that was the first thing that came to my mind. Adding

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    PDLog( @"Received response" );
}
```

solves this problem and makes my network requests appear in the inspector.